# EWS managed API 2.2 StreamingSubscription exception

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm following the Microsoft guidliness to develop an app that uses the StreamingSubscription. It works but I always get an System.ArgumentNullException
on the following code.

```
 ExchangeService srv = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

        //service.AutodiscoverUrl("xx.xx@xxxx.nl");
        srv.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");           
        srv.Url = new Uri("https://xx.xx.nl/ews/exchange.asmx");

        FolderId gpInbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox("xx.xx@xxxx.nl"));

        // Subscribe to streaming notifications in the Inbox. 
        StreamingSubscription sss = srv.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(
            new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },
            EventType.NewMail);

        StreamingSubscriptionConnection c = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(srv, 30);
        {
            c.AddSubscription(sss);
            c.OnNotificationEvent += OnNotificationEvent;
            c.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
            c.Open();
        }
```

The Exception is thrown by

```
StreamingSubscription sss = srv.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(
            new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },
            EventType.NewMail);
```

I can't find the reason why this is throwing an exception. I've installed the latest version of the API via Nuget package

Answer (score 3):

To get the latest version of the EWS Managed API you will need to compile it from GitHub https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api The NuGet version is quite old and hasn't been updated since the source was released publicly . There are number of issues around Subscriptions that have been fixed https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed&utf8=%E2%9C%93 (as well as others not listed) which is probably the cause or your problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've downloaded and recompiled it but it still throws a argument exception. This doesn't cause the app from working. It's more why is it throwing this exception.

Comment: The next thing would be to go through the underlying source code and work out why its throwing an exception and then fix it if it is a bug.